# How to shorten file paths using ellipses in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, path, truncate

In Ruby (not Rails), is there a straightforward way to take a long file path and replace unimportant parts of it with ellipses, to make it shorter for display?

For example:

> a/very/long/path/with/plenty/of/characters/that/won't/fit/on/my/screen/easily

Becomes something like:

> a/very/lo.../screen/easily

I need to be able to specify the maximum length; and the start and end of the path should always be visible.

I could probably figure out a solution if I bang my head against it for long enough, but perhaps someone knows a way?

Comment: What if the first and the last segment is longer than the maximum length? What rule should win? The max length or that the start and the end of the path should always be visible?

Comment: Good question. I guess the last segment would be more important than the first; and the length would be most important.

Comment: Why does it become `a/very/lo.../screen/easily` and not `a/very/long/...reen/easily` (i.e. simply cut in half) – what are the rules for selecting the _"unimportant parts"_?

Comment: It was merely an example, I didn't specifically count the characters. It could well be either of those. Perhaps I should have been more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat like this:

```
shortener = ->(path, length) {
  l = length / 2 - 1
  [path[0...l], path[-l..-1]].join('..')
}
shortener.(path, 10)
#⇒ "a/ve..sily"
```

Comment: Nice. That's pretty damn simple. And while there are potential improvements that could be made (such as ensuring that ellipses only happen directly before or after a path separator unless there's insufficient space to do so), it probably wouldn't be worth the extra effort to implement. Thanks, I'll give this one a try in my program.

Comment: If `length` is odd you are hiding one extra char

Comment: @Panic that’s why I preamble it with “somewhat like that.” The accurate implementation depends on many factors and custom wishes; the above is the barebone only.

Comment: @SodAlmighty if you want to split on path separators, you might want to `path.split($/)` and then `take_while` from both the beginning and the end until the total length is near the desired one.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin Good idea.

Answer (score 3):

I've used left and right pointers (`lt_ptr` and `rt_ptr`) to build that two portions of the string that are to be retained and separated by an ellipsis.

I begin by reducing the right pointer to the last forward slash, then increase the left pointer to the first forward slash, then reduce the right pointer to the next-to-last forward slash, and so on until further movements of the pointer would make the string containing the ellipsis longer than the maximum permissible length.

**Code**

```
def shorten_string(str, max_len, ellipsis = '...')
  return str if str.size <= max_len
  max_len -= ellipsis.size
  ops = [{ index: :index, ptr: 0, chg: 1 },
         { index: :rindex, ptr: str.size-1, chg: -1 } ].cycle
  op = ops.next
  success = true
  loop do
    op = ops.next
    ptr = str.public_send(op[:index], '/', op[:ptr] + op[:chg] )
    lptr = ptr
    rptr = ops.peek[:ptr]
    lptr, rptr = rptr, lptr if op[:index] == :rindex
    if lptr + 1 + str.size - rptr <= max_len
      op[:ptr] = ptr
    else
      break unless success
      success = false
    end        
  end
  op = ops.next if op[:index] == :rindex
  "%s%s%s" % [str[0..op[:ptr]], ellipsis, str[ops.peek[:ptr]..-1]]
end
```

**Examples**

```
str = 'a/very/long/path/with/too/many/characters/to/fit/on/my/screen/easily'
```

```
shorten_string(str, 40)
  #=> "a/very/long/path/.../on/my/screen/easily" (length: 40)
shorten_string(str, 30)
  #=> "a/very/.../on/my/screen/easily"           (length: 30)
shorten_string(str, 20)
  #=> "a/.../screen/easily"                      (length: 19)
```

It is of course coincidence that, in the first two examples, the length of the resulting string (with the ellipsis) was exactly equal to the maximum length, `max_length`. Notice that in the second example there are 4 forward slashes after the ellipsis and only 2 before. That's because after `"/my"` was added only 3 more characters could be added, not enough for `"long/"` (which follows `"very/"`), but enough for `"/on"`.

**Explanation**

This uses the forms of [String#index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-index) and [String#rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-rindex) that employ a second argument.

To better understand the calculations that are being performed, I suggest running the code against an example, after salting the code with `puts` statements. An example of the modified method follows.

```
def shorten_string(str, max_len, ellipsis = '...')
  return str if str.size <= max_len
  max_len -= ellipsis.size
  puts "str.size=#{str.size}"                                   #!!!!
  ops = [{ index: :index, ptr: 0, chg: 1 },
         { index: :rindex, ptr: str.size-1, chg: -1 } ].cycle
  op = ops.next
  success = true
  loop do
    op = ops.next
    puts "\nop=#{op}, ops.peek=#{ops.peek}"                     #!!!!
    ptr = str.public_send(op[:index], '/', op[:ptr] + op[:chg] )
    lptr = ptr
    rptr = ops.peek[:ptr]
    puts "ptr=#{ptr}, lptr=#{lptr}, rptr=#{rptr}"               #!!!!
    lptr, rptr = rptr, lptr if op[:index] == :rindex
    puts "after possible flip, lptr=#{lptr}, rptr=#{rptr}"      #!!!!
    puts "lptr + 1 + str.size - rptr = #{lptr+1+str.size-rptr}" #!!!!
    if lptr + 1 + str.size - rptr <= max_len
      op[:ptr] = ptr
      puts "after lptr+1+str.size-rptr <= max_len, op=#{op}"    #!!!!
    else
      break unless success
      success = false
    end        
  end
  puts "after loop op=#{op}, ops.peek=#{ops.peek}"              #!!!!
  op = ops.next if op[:index] == :rindex
  "%s%s%s" % [str[0..op[:ptr]], ellipsis, str[ops.peek[:ptr]..-1]]
end
```

Comment: It looks a bit like Fortran but the output looks really nice.

Comment: @Eric, Fortran II or IV?  I cannot disagree.  Perhaps I should have broken the string into an array, worked on that and the joined, but I generally like to work on strings without doing that.

Comment: Very nice. Shame it replaces the entire segment with ellipses, instead of truncating the segment, but a nice piece of code nonetheless.

Comment: I'm toying with the idea of repeatedly chopping the last segment and the first segment off a path until insufficient length remains, then concatenating the remainder, truncating it, and adding ellipses. I will have to give that a try.

Comment: Sod, regarding your first comment, I see I misread the question. It's *much* easier if one need not break on entire segments.

Comment: I was thinking it'd be best if it truncated on only one end of a segment (i.e. /something.../ rather than /something...something/) but it's really not worth the effort at this point. Plus, I now realise that this would create the false impression that no segments had been entirely omitted, which wouldn't always be the case. These solutions will do fine. Yours was very detailed and I thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Your comment "I'm toying with the idea..." prompted me to return to my initial answer with improvements I had incorporated in later versions. It still doesn't meet your requirement of not necessarily breaking on segments. I've made all these changes just out of curiousity.

Answer (score 0):

```
ELLIPSIS = '...'
SEPARATOR = '\\'


def truncate_at_middle_of_filename(filename: str, maxlength: int):
    # nothing to do, already fits
    print(f'Original : {filename}   length {len(filename)}')
    if len(filename) <= maxlength:
        return filename
    segments = filename.split(SEPARATOR)

    return _remove_segment_one_by_one(segments, maxlength)


def _remove_segment_one_by_one(segments: list, maxlength: int):
    newstring = SEPARATOR.join(segments)
    while len(newstring) > maxlength:
        splitpoint = len(segments) // 2
        try:
            segments[splitpoint] = ELLIPSIS
            newstring = SEPARATOR.join(segments)
            del segments[splitpoint]
        except:
            return ""

    return newstring

result = truncate_at_middle_of_filename("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\catroot\\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}",60)
print(f'Truncated: {result}   length {len(result)}')

# Truncated: C:\Windows\...\{F750E6C3-38EE-11D1-85E5-00C04FC295EE}   length 53
```